# Django - How can I INSERT values to a second database

Tags: django

I've a Django project that I need to start storing the hits on pages. I'm thinking to do it to a second database. The models on this second database will be not present in the Master database.

Question 1:

Django will handle this kind of thing? It is possible to create the models only to a second database?

Question 2:

Is this the best approach, to write this kind of data to a second database and use a queue system like RabbitMQ to handle these INSERTS.

Question 3:

There is out there any examples on how can I setup a second Database on Django and write to it?

Best Regards,

Comment: Really, google for "django multiple databases" and follow [the first hit] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. The database setting allows more than one database (it's a dictionary).
You will have to customize a lot of things though.
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/ for further specs

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'users': {
       'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```